# Android Profiler shows others section taking a lot of memory than expected

Tags: android, memory-management, android-profiler

I ran Android Profiler on my App since it was slow in simple user interactions. When I ran the profiler it showed 150 mib memory used by 'others' category. After searching on official forums here: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler.html

It says " Memory used by your app that the system isn't sure how to categorize.
"

What does that mean? and how to rectify the issue?

Please refer the Android Profiler screenshot:

[image: Android Profiler Screenshot]

Comment: Are you caching many elements in your app?

Comment: its a two screen app in which on the first screen i read the nfc tag and on second screen i fetch content from server based on tag id. This is the first screen post launch data of profiler.